# Confused with the output related to character and wchar_t

Tags: c++

Not able to understand whats happening in the below code

```
wchar_t wc;

wc =L'ab';

char ch = 'ab';
```

When i am debugging the above code , i found that a is stored in `wc` where as `b` is stored in `ch` .
I dont understand why `a` is not being stored inside the `ch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's compiler defined behavior:

On VS2012, I get `'a'`, `'b'` output

on gcc 4.7.2, I get `'b'`, `'b'` output and I get warning when I compile it:

```
warning: character constant too long for its type [enabled by default]
warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

Answer (score 5):

6.4.4.4 para 10 of the spec:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, **is implementation-defined**

In other words a different compiler may do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

From the standard:

> A multicharacter literal has type int and **implementation-defined** value.

So you initialize the char `ch` with an (implementation defined) int which in turn is turned into a char. That char happens to be 'b'.

It wouldn't surprise me if the compiler issued a warning here also, esp. with the `-Wall` compiler flag or similar.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you shouldn't assain two characters to these single character variables. It's incorrect at all.

Then when I tried to compile your code by my VC2010, I got warning message C4066 for the line "wc = L'ab';", and got warning messages C4305 and C4309 for the line "char ch = 'ab';".

C4066 tells us the second character was ignored. This is because the compiler considers the type of L'ab' as character. But for the next line, the compiler considers 'ab' as an integer value, not two characters. So I got warning messages C4305 "truncation from int to char" and C4309 "truncation of constant value".